# How to run MobileFirst Platfom Foundation in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, ibm-mobilefirst

I have created a very simple HelloWorldProject (without adapter, database) in eclipse with the moblefirst plugin for learning purpose. It is running in Mobilefirst Development Server.

[image]

I believe at the end of the development, this project have to be moved into production environment. Therefore, I have downloaded Apache Tomcat in local machine and try to deploy the current HelloWorldProject to Apache Tomcat. What I have done is uploading the HelloWorldProject.war into Apache (localhost:8080/manager/html). However it fail to start..

I google around and found out that I have to use IBM installation manager to install mobilefirst on tomcat and use ant task to configure database, adapter settings.

However I cant find anywhere to download IBM installation manager. Is that free?
How should I deploy my HelloWorldProject and running in tomcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not free.

In order to deploy your MobileFirst project into Tomcat, you must buy a license of IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation and use the give artifacts to deploy your project (and additional required files) to the application server, in this case - Tomcat.

Contact IBM for purchasing options.

Comment: Thanks @Idan, I have seen your name in other post too! Too sad to know this is not a free source...

Answer (score -1):

In developerworks paper IBM MobileFirst Flatform Foundation "Scalability and Hardware Sizing", There is a typical deployment with WebSphere Application Server.

https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/additional-documentation/scalability-hardware-sizing-7-1/

But if choosing Tomcat as application server for MFP server farm deployment, which load balance software will been used? Are there any MFP performance report about the comparsion betwwen Webspshere appliation server and tomcat as MFP application server?

Thanks a lot.

Michael